# Error while trying to load an asset: FormatException: Illegal scheme character - error while using image picker

Tags: flutter

I am trying to enable to the app user to change his/her profile picture and upload it via camera or gallery, I used
the [image picker package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) for this purpose,

this is my code snippet:

`

```
class ProfilePic extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePic({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePicState createState() => _ProfilePicState();
}

class _ProfilePicState extends State<ProfilePic> {
  File image = new File("");
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 115,
      width: 115,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage(image.uri.toFilePath()),

            // child: ClipRRect(
            //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            //   child: image != null
            //       ? Image.file(
            //           image,
            //           width: 115,
            //           height: 115,
            //           fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            //         )
            //       : Container(
            //           decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //               color: Colors.grey[100],
            //               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            //           width: 100,
            //           height: 100,
            //           child: Icon(
            //             Icons.camera_alt,
            //             color: Colors.grey[800],
            //           ),
            //         ),
            // ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: -16,
            bottom: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 46,
              width: 46,
              child: FlatButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
                onPressed: () {
                  _showPicker(context);
                },
                child: SvgPicture.asset("icons/cameraIcon.svg"),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _imgFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  _imgFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  void _showPicker(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: new Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListTile(
                      leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                      title: new Text('Gallerie'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _imgFromGallery();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                  new ListTile(
                    leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                    title: new Text('Caméra'),
                    onTap: () {
                      _imgFromCamera();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

`
PS: I am using Chrome for debugging.

Its select the image from the device but doesn't change the state to upload the image, am asking if it is a flutter web related problem so in a real device or emulator can work smoothly?

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

`AssetImage` takes asset files that you have referenced in your `pubspec.yaml`. you should use `FileImage` instead if you are trying to display images from the camera or gallery.

example: `FileImage(image)`

You can read more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/assets)

Comment: actually you are right i am begginer to flutter, but i used Image.file in the commented code but didn't worked as well

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should be FileImage(image)

Comment: i used FileImage like this `CircleAvatar(
              // backgroundImage: AssetImage(image.uri.toFilePath()),
              child: Image(
            image: FileImage(image, scale: 4),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          )` but getting same error, i am debugging on Chrome do you think i should use  dart:html instead of dart:io, anyway i am going to try